# Importing module into file that gets generated by setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools, pickler

At the moment I try to import something into the file that gets generated by Setuptools and setup.py.
The file it generates at the moment looks like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
from scripts.trans import main
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

and I need to import this into the generated code to get my code work: 
`from casepunc.utils import WordTokenizer`
So it looks like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
import sys
from scripts.trans import main
from casepunc.utils import WordTokenizer
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

This is a dependency and it have to be in the `__main__` module otherwise I get an AttributeError that it can't be found.

Background is that I got an external Model saved with PyTorch / Pickler that I need to get loaded. Its a common Problem but because of SetupUtils I can't just paste the needed import into the `__main__` module like suggested.

Does anybody know how I can archive this import or any other workaround?